# How to pass a variable through two nested anonymous function (an event handler with a timeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some code that cycles through each `id` and adds a character count handler. Because I needed to pass the `id` variable to the handler function, I needed to use this anonymous function with `event.data.param1`.

```
$('#comment_editor' + id).on("click dbclick mousedown mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseup keydown keypress keyup blur change focus select", {param1: id},
function (event) {
    comment_change(event.data.param1);
});
```

Paste and cut need a fix when adding a handler because they are delayed, so the handler needs to have a timeout before doing what it needs to do. Again, I need to pass the `id` variable to the handler, but I also need to pass it through the timeout. I set it up, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#comment_editor'+updates[i][0]).on("paste cut", {param1:id},
    function (event) {
        setTimeout(
            function (event) {
                comment_change(event.data.param1);
            }, 1);
    }
);
}
```

How can I get the past/cut handler to accept the `id` variable?

Comment: but you didn't pass the data in the second piece of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `event` from function param you send to timeout:

```
$('#comment_editor' + id).on("paste cut",
    function (event) {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                comment_change(event.data.param1, id);
            }, 1);
    }
);
```

That way your `event` will be 'inherited' from outer closure.

Comment: Works perfectly. I thought I had to pass the variable into the timeout function, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to `id` within the for, because when the handlers will be executed the `id` will always refer to the last value that was processed inside the loop.

Therefore should move the handler creation to another method like `getHandlerFor(id)`. This way you can bind each one of the `id`s to the context of that method, and you'll be able to refer to the `id` directly from within the functions.

like:

```
var getHandlerFor = function (id) {
    return function (event) {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                // use id without worries, since it has been bound to the context of this method.
                comment_change(event.data.param1);
            }, 1);
    };
};

/* ... */

for(var id in ids){
    $('#comment_editor' + id).on("paste cut", getHandlerFor(id));
}
```

Comment: The OP _can_ refer to `id` within a for loop, because the way he or she is using it isn't used at all within the event handler function being bound. That's the whole point of setting the `{param1:id}` data. The code you've shown won't work because it still refers to `event.data.param1` within the handler, but you've removed the parameter to `.on()` that was setting the data.